# Pskill doesn't work when loading a page with PHP (and doesn't kill the process)

Tags: php, shell, command, loading, kill

I must kill remotely a process (for example calc.exe) but when I try to load my PHP page on internet it keeps loading and does nothing here is multiple techniques I have used but none of them work:

```
exec("pskill \\\\ipadress calc -u user -p pass")

exec("pskill \\ipadress calc -u user -p pass")

exec("pskill \\\\ipadress calc -u user -p pass >NUL")

exec("C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k kill_myprogram.bat");
--> "pskill \\ip calc.exe -u user-p pass"
```

and:

```
WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C C:\path\toto.vbs", 0, false);
---> Set OShell=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strCommand="pskill \\adress -u user -p pass program"
OShell.Run strCommand 
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C C:\path\kill_myprogram.bat", 0, false)
```

Comment: For paths in PHP, I'd use the forward slash - it will convert it. The backslash may be being escaped in your `exec` with the full path in it. I wonder whether this doesn't work because your web server does not have the right permissions to kill off tasks as you do from the console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try it .. but if it doesn't work I don't know what to do because with a cmd it is fine it kills the process remotely but with the php I can't do it ( sorry for bad english )

Comment: I believe you can give your web server process more permissions, I think you do this in IIS (but it's been too many years since I've done this). I suspect it would have been answered here before though, have a search?

Comment: I will look into this direction if it works i will post here how :)

Comment: (I assume you're using IIS and not Apache? Of course, you'll need to set permissions for the server you're using).

Comment: hmm i think it is Apache ( Apache HTTP Server )

Comment: When i am in Process Explorer I see :
 cmd.exe
    pskill.exe but it does nothing .. but it is running

Comment: I found how to do ! pskill.exe was freezing the page because it was waiting an argument : exec('cmd.exe /C START yourpath/your_kill.bat')

In the .bat :

call pskill \yourname -u user -p pass program -accepteula >> eventual_log_file.txt

But now I have an other problem .. i would like to pass a parameter from PHP to the .bat for example : exec('cmd.exe /C START mypath/mykill.bat parameter1')

in the .bat : call pskill \myparameter ...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22961816/472495) from today - you need to escape strings injected into exec commands.