# How to use exec shell with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I want to use an exec shell in PHP code by connecting to a database. I had used this block of code but it doesn't work! I don't know what might be the problem, so this is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit4']))

{
$results = shell_exec("cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep" . $_POST['key'] . "| sed s/'^.*apache2'/''/g | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | cat ");
echo $results ;

}

else if(isset($_POST['submit5']))
{
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1',"root"," ") or die("erreur de connexion au serveur");
    mysql_select_db("lastnline");
        $sql='Select * from motclef';    
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))

    {
$results = shell_exec("cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep" . $row['nom'] . "| sed s/'^.*apache2'/''/g | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | cat ");
echo $results ;

    }       
}
```

The submit4 works very good but the submit5 doesn't work :/

Comment: I guess something is wrong, since it `doesn't work`

Comment: I can execute arbitrary commands on your server.

Comment: When you find yourself using the phrase "doesn't work", stop, and instead state (a) what you expected to happen, and (b) what actually happened. "Doesn't work" is the least helpful error report possible `;)`.

Comment: please is this block of code right or not : $results = shell_exec("cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep" . $row['nom'] . "| sed s/'^.*apache2'/''/g | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | cat ");
echo $results ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But never populate input values directly into a shell command. Use the function `escapeshellarg()`:

```
$key = escapeshellarg($_POST['key']);
```

Comment: thx for helping but my code works and very good it was just a typo between field of my db  instead of : grep" . $row['nom'] . " i should used grep" . $row['word'] . " because in my table i have 2 fields id + word :)  and thx a lot !! i know that ure not a  programming-babysitter because u didnt help me i had found my mistake alone!

Comment: first step to perfection ;)

Comment: @user3445535, please do take hek2mgl's advice though - your code is vulnerable to serious security issues at present.

Comment: why can u explain more  !!

Comment: because someone might send `foo ; cat db.config.php` in `POST['key']`